# Select multiple tables with same column

Tags: sql, union

I have two tables, with the same structure of columns.
The first table has data from 2019.
And now I want to add date from 2020 and later from 2021.
How can I do this?
Union, but how?

```
SELECT cast(cast( Replace(xy,',','.') as float) as datetime) xy
, [xy1]
, cast(xy2 as int) xy2
, [xy3]
, cast( Replace(xy4,',','.') as float) xy4
, [xy5]
, cast( Replace(xy6,',','.') as float) xy6
, cast( Replace([xy7],',','.') as float) [xy7]
, cast( Replace([xy8],',','.') as float) [xy8]
, cast( Replace([xy9],',','.') as float) [xy9]
, [xy10]
FROM 2019
WHERE xy7 not like '#%'
```

Both table have this structure.

```
2019
x| xy1| xy2 | xy3 etc etc etc
2020
x| xy1| xy2 | xy3 etc etc etc
```

Comment: "Structured Query Language (SQL) is a language for querying databases. Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data, and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used. If your question relates solely to a specific DBMS (uses specific extensions/features), use that DBMS's tag instead. Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL." (see: [SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql)) ==> Please correct the tags!

Comment: Do you really need float, or is this better?: `cast( Replace(xy4,',','.') as decimal(8,2))`  this will just result in 2 decimals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
SELECT cast(cast( Replace(xy,',','.') as float) as datetime) xy
, [xy1]
, cast(xy2 as int) xy2
, [xy3]
, cast( Replace(xy4,',','.') as float) xy4
, [xy5]
, cast( Replace(xy6,',','.') as float) xy6
, cast( Replace([xy7],',','.') as float) [xy7]
, cast( Replace([xy8],',','.') as float) [xy8]
, cast( Replace([xy9],',','.') as float) [xy9]
, [xy10]
FROM 2019
WHERE xy7 not like '#%'
UNION ALL
SELECT cast(cast( Replace(xy,',','.') as float) as datetime) xy
, [xy1]
, cast(xy2 as int) xy2
, [xy3]
, cast( Replace(xy4,',','.') as float) xy4
, [xy5]
, cast( Replace(xy6,',','.') as float) xy6
, cast( Replace([xy7],',','.') as float) [xy7]
, cast( Replace([xy8],',','.') as float) [xy8]
, cast( Replace([xy9],',','.') as float) [xy9]
, [xy10]
FROM 2020
WHERE xy7 not like '#%'
```

You can use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` if you don't want duplicates

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte
as
(
select * from 2019 WHERE xy7 not like '#%'
union all
select * from 2020 WHERE xy7 not like '#%'
union all
select * from 2021 WHERE xy7 not like '#%'
)
SELECT cast(cast( Replace(xy,',','.') as float) as datetime) xy
, [xy1]
, cast(xy2 as int) xy2
, [xy3]
, cast( Replace(xy4,',','.') as float) xy4
, [xy5]
, cast( Replace(xy6,',','.') as float) xy6
, cast( Replace([xy7],',','.') as float) [xy7]
, cast( Replace([xy8],',','.') as float) [xy8]
, cast( Replace([xy9],',','.') as float) [xy9]
, [xy10]
FROM cte
```